# AdexchangebuyerService.Creatives.List call gets stuck using Google.Apis.Adexchangebuyer.v13

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

In the following code, **sometimes** the execution gets stuck:

```
var listRequest = this.AdexchangebuyerService.Creatives.List();
listRequest.MaxResults = 1000;
var listOfCreatives = listRequest.Execute(); // -- execution hangs here and does not time out
```

I am considering using the async Execute call and setting a timeout on it, but wanted to check if this is a known issue or bug, and to let the client lib devs know and see if they have suggestions/fixes...

Comment: could you try testing with try it at the bottom of this page? https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/buyer-rest/v1.3/creatives/list see if this lags as well?

Comment: I never had an issue running it from the try it page, just using the client lib

Comment: What platform are you using? Is it a WP, regular .NET app, etc.?

Comment: This is running in a windows service written in C# using the Google.Apis.Adexchangebuyer.v13 client library version 1.9.0.51

Comment: Did you try to run the async-await version, did it stuck as well? Did you manage to understand what is the frequency and understand *sometimes* better?

Comment: I tried with async-await version, and it still got stuck, it happens like one out of 10 times. I am calling it async now and doing wait on the task with a timeout, then throwing if not completed to get out.